# Why does Google Maps ask me to rate places I haven't been to?

Tags: google-maps

I am asked to rate places Google Maps thinks I have visited. I have not been there and I click on "I have not been there". But the next time, I still get asked to rate those places I have chosen as "I have not been there" before.

How can I stop Maps from asking me to rate places I haven't been to?

Answer (score 1):

If you were near a business for enough time to count, Maps might guess the you visited the business.

GPS location is imperfect, esp. with multiple businesses in the same building or GPS signal reflections among tall buildings.

WiFi location might also apply, and sometimes WiFi base stations get moved to new locations.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is logged in to your Googe account on another device and visits the place in question it might push the notification to your device.

Comment: Nobody is logged in to my account but thank you